# How to drop quotation for TEXTs in pgAdmin?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

For some reason my PgAdmin by default adds `" "` to any string.

for example:

```
select 'a'::citext as name
```

gives:

```
name
citext
------
a
```

if I copy the contact from the column it gives `"a"`.
I want it to give only `a`. without the `" "`. How can I set it ?

I'm using pgAdming 1.18.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Preference panel, under the "Query tool -> Result grid" option, you can see several options.

The option: "Result copy quote character" has the default value double quote (")

You can change it to an empty string to obtain what you need.